# How to load large JSON file into javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

Firstly, thanks for taking time to view my post. I am working on a project with a few people, and we basically have a webpage, and once you log in, it displays all the data from a mysql database which has 6 tables, 3 of which have data in them. We figured out that in order for us to go about this, we need to transfer data by exporting the data into  JSON file(s), then from there load the JSON files into java script so it can communicate with the web server. We were wondering what would be the best way to go about this. One way we found out is to reference the JSON ddata as variables and just list everything out, but several of our files have loads and loads of data. Would there be an easier approach?

This would be the first time we are doing something like this, so we are learning and appreciate your feedback!!

Comment: Why would you export to JSON file, why not load it directly?

Comment: you mean load it directly from .mysql file?

Comment: Directly via SQL service...

Comment: but from what we understood is that you cant display sql data directly to browser, no? like as soon as you put in credentials, all the 3 tables get displayed in the browser

Comment: Well it's like this, you make an ajax request using javascript, that request is processed by PHP, ASP.NET or even node.js, it opens a connection with SQL, fetches the data and returns it as a response to that ajax request.

Comment: they mentioned specifically that we cannot use php- only javascript and json?

Comment: If you'd told us that in your post, maybe you wouldn't have received down votes. Well in that case, loading data from JSON file is your only option.

Comment: ummm, well I didn't see that last comment (by Ray Lako) when I posted my answer, but.... Why must it be only javascript and json?

Comment: dude we were asking the same thing. they told us only javascript and json

Comment: well, there is one thought that come to mind. I know of a database called Mongo. I believe it is free to use. From what little I know about it. It is an actual database (JSON is a data-structure, JSON is NOT a database. Mongo uses JSON), and I believe it is NoSQL. Now I don't know how communication works with NoSQL, what is required or anything. It may not work, I don't know enough about it to really say. I just know, it uses JSON specificly. Even with this said, I highly recommend reconsidering PHP, and if so, looking at my answer as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some kind of AJAX library, you can easily request the .json file from the browser.

For example with jQuery:

```
$.post("ourJSONFile.json", function( data ) {
  ..logic to display data..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE - The comment about no PHP was not posted while I was writing this. Until I know why there can be no PHP, I'm just going to leave this answer here.

I think you're going at this in the wrong way. There is no need for JSON here, just query your database for the information.

The overview of what you need to do is (in PHP or the language you use to talk with your server) you  need to

- connect to the database
- query database for information (query in your case, more or less means get the information)
- do something with the returned information (such as echoing it in PHP so it will go to the user)

Now, it doesn't look like there is much effort place for getting this done, only planning. So, I'll just show you a few links to read up. (Which is also why people has devoted your question, Stackoverflow doesn't like asking question with no effort to research answers)

I'd use php.net for looking up methods, such as the mysqli_query method. This is very useful for learning small but important things about the method, like what it returns when an error occurs.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Taking a quick look through this guide, I think it should suffice. Besides syntax and such, some other important points are use MySQLI (when using PHP 5 or higher) and use prepared statements.

http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

The use of prepared statements is to protect your queries from injections. w3schools gives a good explanation about this @ http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

MySQLI is MySQL Improved, it is more secured and supported. MySQL has been deprecated since PHP 5, and php.net pages on a MySql method will actually say this at the very top.

Finally, Andrew mentioned AJAX. AJAX is (for example) a way of doing things that would normally require reloading the page, without reloading the page. There is more to that, and I would recommand looking into it once you get use to the languages you are using.

Note, AJAX does not require libraries to use, it can be done with pure javascript. Libraries simply (as seen around) simplify AJAX a lot.